# How to remove tags using regex / pattern in java

Tags: java, regex

I have a string "`<li>test<ul></ul><li>test<ul><li>model<ul></ul><li>src<ul><li>org<ul>"`", and i want to remove the pattern "`<li>test<ul></ul>`" from the string.
So my desired output will be "`<li>test<ul><li>src<ul><li>org<ul>`"

I have tried following way.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "<li>test<ul></ul><li>test<ul><li>model<ul></ul><li>src<ul><li>org<ul>";
        str = str.replaceAll("(?s)<li>.*?<ul></ul>", "");
        System.out.println(str);
    }

}
```

but it is not worked and I got output as "`<li>src<ul><li>org<ul>`"

Comment: have look in my answer, it should work i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and replace by ""

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "<li>test<ul></ul><li>test<ul><li>model<ul></ul><li>src<ul><li>org<ul>";
    str = str.replaceAll("<li>([^<]*)<ul><\\/ul>", "");
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Edit:

Here's the explanation as requested: 
reg engine will start matching for anything in between `<li>` and `<ul></ul>`. `[^<]*` will make sure that there is no "<" sign in between  ... which is making it kind of lazy which could also be done by using .*?.

Comment: Could you explain your answer rather than just dumping the code in here and then begging for upvotes?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you are quite grasping how RegExs work.

Take a look here: http://regexr.com/3ebpv

Basically, your regex is matching on two parts:

`<li>test<ul></ul>` *and* `<li>test<ul><li><model><ul></ul>.`

Thus leaving you with only: `<li>src<ul><li>org<ul>`

If you specifically want to remove the pattern `<li>test<ul></ul>`,
Then why are you not using that as the exact thing to replace? That isn't a Regular Expression, it's an exact string you want to find and replace. You're thinking way too hard for a simple problem.

This should suffice, no?

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "<li>test<ul></ul><li>test<ul><li>model<ul></ul><li>src<ul><li>org<ul>";
        str = str.replaceAll("<li>src<ul><li>org<ul>", "");
        System.out.println(str);
    }

}
```